# python array indexing when using for arange loops

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, range

I have a question. I am currently moving over from matlab to python and whilst I found it easy to adapt to numpy and scipy some parts are still a bit enigmatic ;)

What I want to do is calculate data in two nested loops and put (reshape) it into an (m,n) array to make a contour plot.

So I thought about the following:

```
for i in arange(1, 10, 1):
    for k in arange(5, 50, 5):
        res = do_something(i, k)
```

but now I am not entirely sure how I should put this into the right shape (in Matlab I would just index the loops with i=1:1:10 and so on and pull the actual value of i out of a vector...).

I could append the results res.append(res) and reshape it with res.reshape((m,n)). But there might be a more elegant way of doing so?

Every help is very welcome!

best wishes,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution that doesn't need the explict index to store the values

```
result = [[my_function(x, y)
           for x in arange(0.3, 10.7, 2.2)]
          for y in arange(-3.2, 5.4, 0.7)]
```

For cases in which you need the explict index using `enumerate(arange(...))` is both compact and readable.

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to build large matrices with numpy however (if you need some speed then you should decompose the function in multiple simple operations each one performed explicitly with numpy).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do your loops to match the indices of the result in the result array rather than the parameters in your computational function.

```
result = numpy.zeros((n,m), dtype=float) # I'm assuming your results are float.
for i in range(10):
    for k in range(10):
        res[i,j] = do_something(i+1, 5k+5) #don't forget range(M) starts at 0 and ends at M-1 (giving you M values)
```